# Align input fields on an Infusionsoft form

Tags: css, forms, infusionsoft

how do i align the input fields on an Infusionsoft form as you can see on this page:

https://www.nurturingai.com/test-page/

This is the code for the form:

First Name *
        
    
    
        Email *
        
    
    
         
    
    
        Submit

I need a quick bit of CSS to align them.

Comment: can you include the code?

Comment: post what you have already tried

Comment: This is the code for the form: